# how to return a list of values from n tuples

Tags: python, data-structures

I have several tuples, and I built a "tree" structure like this using graphviz:
[image]

`edge= [('CDDC', '4C35'), ('4C35', 'BE83'), ('13E8', '7A21'), ('7A21', '7D43'), ('7D43', 'A7F6'), ('A7F6', '9526'), ('A7F6', '09D2'), ('09D2', '6DEA'), ('6DEA', '9290'), ('6245', '795A'), ('9290', 'F7BB'), ('F7BB', '2ABD'), ('2ABD', 'FE11'), ('FE11', 'F64C'), ('795A', 'EAD0'), ('EAD0', '86E4'), ('13E8', '01D7'), ('86E4', '88F6'), ('88F6', '2E95'), ('EDC6', '26C7')]`

what I want to achieve now is to a return a list of values for each branch/leaf
Take the second tree for example, I want to return

```
[13E8, 7A21, 7D43,A7F6],
[A7F6, 9525],
[A7F6, 09D2, 6DEA, 9290]
```

,

Any guidance on how to do it? Thank you.

Comment: Can you also share what would be the use case of this question? From this second example given, I see that node `A7F6` is an articulation point for that graph. Just wondering if that can be factor based on which the lists in the result can be split.

Comment: @subasri_ you can think of this is cell culture. I have a root cell `13E8`, then it gradually evolves, but it's child `9526`dies. I want to know the evolution process for each split basically. I want to know the parent and its child/children.

Comment: Do a depth-first search on the tree. Keep an accumulator variable that contains the list of nodes that you want to return. Add this list to your results and reset it, everytime you reach a node that has more than one child.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do a depth-first search on the tree. Keep an accumulator variable that contains the list of nodes that you want to return. Add this list to your results and reset it, everytime you reach a node that has more than one child.

Since the syntax you showed looks like python:

```py
from itertools import chain

# takes a list of edges
# returns a dict mapping parent to list of children
def build_dict(edges):
    graph = {}
    for parent, child in edges:
        graph.setdefault(parent, []).append(child)
    return graph

# identify nodes that don't have parents
def get_roots(forest):
    return set(forest.keys()).difference(chain.from_iterable(forest.values()))

# depth-first-search
def gen_segments(tree, root, acc=None):
    if acc is None:
        acc = []
    acc.append(root)
    children = tree.get(root, [])
    if len(children) == 1:
        yield from gen_segments(tree, children[0], acc)
    else:
        yield acc
        for child in children:
            yield from gen_segments(tree, child, [root])

def gen_segments_from_forest(forest):
    for root in get_roots(forest):
        yield from gen_segments(forest, root)

edges= [('CDDC', '4C35'), ('4C35', 'BE83'), ('13E8', '7A21'), ('7A21', '7D43'), ('7D43', 'A7F6'), ('A7F6', '9526'), ('A7F6', '09D2'), ('09D2', '6DEA'), ('6DEA', '9290'), ('6245', '795A'), ('9290', 'F7BB'), ('F7BB', '2ABD'), ('2ABD', 'FE11'), ('FE11', 'F64C'), ('795A', 'EAD0'), ('EAD0', '86E4'), ('13E8', '01D7'), ('86E4', '88F6'), ('88F6', '2E95'), ('EDC6', '26C7')]

forest = build_dict(edges)

print(list(gen_segments_from_forest(forest)))
```

Output:

```
[['EDC6', '26C7'],
 ['13E8'],
 ['13E8', '7A21', '7D43', 'A7F6'],
 ['A7F6', '9526'],
 ['A7F6', '09D2', '6DEA', '9290', 'F7BB', '2ABD', 'FE11', 'F64C'],
 ['13E8', '01D7'],
 ['6245', '795A', 'EAD0', '86E4', '88F6', '2E95'],
 ['CDDC', '4C35', 'BE83']]
```